# Splitting a matrix into multiple columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, multiple-columns

Let's say I have the two column matrix `M=[0,1;2,3;4,5]` and I want to split them simultaneously into two vectors. Want I want to do is `[A,B] = M` so `A=[0;2;4]` and `B=[1;3;5]` but this doesn't work.
Is there some way I could do this in one line of code? My actual matrix has about 20 columns, so storing them in one line would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why is `A` inherently better than `M(:,1)`? Except for the fact that you can't loop over `A,B,C,...` without resorting to some nasty code...

Comment: I need this because the vectors have a special meaning and I need to select later a subset according to the variable name. If I use indices then I don't know what their meaning is since there is no variable name

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn It is best to use some other method (besides variable names) to indicate *true meaning* of your data.

Comment: How do you intend to select the variables later using their name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is a combination of [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).

```
M = rand(4,2);

    0.8173    0.2599
    0.8687    0.8001
    0.0844    0.4314
    0.3998    0.9106


inputData = num2cell(M, 1);
[A, B] = deal(inputData{:});


A =

    0.8173
    0.8687
    0.0844
    0.3998

B =

    0.2599
    0.8001
    0.4314
    0.9106
```

Alternately, as [suggested by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186489/splitting-a-matrix-into-multiple-columns/36186600?noredirect=1#comment60010509_36186600) you can omit `deal`:

```
[A, B] = inputData{:};
```

That being said, when you get to a larger number of elements, just leave them in a cell array rather than trying to juggle 20 variables.

```
columns = num2cell(M, 1);

    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried this before but M was already a cell array so I skipped the conversion to cell, which is critical.

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn While this may solve your direct issue. I would highly recommend the advice of beaker and excaza in the initial comments. If your data is the same size, consider putting it into a 2D array as performance will be much better.

Comment: No need to use `deal`: `[A,B]=inputData{:};`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for pointing that out. I keep forgetting that because I hadn't actually seen that syntax until a few weeks back.

Comment: With recent MATLAB versions, there is only one real use-case left for deal, when you want to assign the same content to multiple variables. For example `[A,B,C,D]=deal(zeros(n))` to have typical preallocation code. For all other cases `deal` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Suever: Take a look at the official docs. Example 1 demonstrates deal, Example 2 the same. Example 3 demonstrates how to do 1 and 2 without deal.

Comment: No docs directly explaining that it is only required for that use-case I mentioned, but no other use-case is explained.

Comment: @Daniel I was more curious about the documentation of `[A,B] = data{:};` as I would like to know when that was introduced.

Comment: [R2006a](http://de.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2006a/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-56475.html) or earlier. To my knowledge comma separated lists where already present earlier but undocumented.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the link! I never knew what to search for to find that. Much appreciated.